# Replacing parentheses with minus figure ("-") + contents of parentheses in notepad++

Tags: regex, parsing, replace, notepad++, converters

I have some simple sales figures in notepad++ of the form

```
($12 000)
($9 000)
```

etc. etc.

I would like to change them from this form to

```
-120000
-90000
```

etc.

I'm sure this is possible with regex/find-replace somehow. What is the best way for me to accomplish this within notepad++?

```
Find : (\d)
Replace : -\d
```

doesn't get me anywhere.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If one of these answers worked please considering accepting one and closing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
\((\$\d+\s\d+)\)
```

Use this as the replacement:

```
-\1
```

Make sure the *Regular expression* radio button is checked.

RegexBuddy generates the following explanation for the regex:

Explanation

```
\((\$\d+\s\d+)\)

Match the character "(" literally «\(»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\$\d+\s\d+)»
  Match the character "$" literally «\$»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match a single character that is a "whitespace character" (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.) «\s»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character ")" literally «\)»
```